# Trying to Create localStorage Not Working (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I need to pull inventory data to my NextJS app, I am then trying to store that data to localStorage, but it never gets set. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (process.browser && localStorage.getItem('inv') === undefined) {
    const inv = await getInventory()
    localStorage.setItem('inv', inv)
  }
```

getInventory() is just a node script that pulls inventory data from a remote api and returns fullInventory.

Here is the code from getInventory():

```
const getInventory = async () => {
  const token = await refreshToken()
  const header = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  };

  const queries = await getQueriesCount();

  axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
  }, async function (error) {
    await new Promise(function (res) {
      setTimeout(function () { res() }, 2000);
    });

    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      const refreshedHeader = await setHeader()
      axios.defaults.headers = refreshedHeader
      originalRequest.headers = refreshedHeader
      return Promise.resolve(axios(originalRequest));
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

  let fullInventory = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < queries; i++) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios({
          url: `${MyApi}/Item.json&offset=${i * 100}&customSku=!~,`,
          method: "get",
          headers: header,
        });

        console.log(`adding items ${i * 100} through ${(i + 1) * 100}`);
        const items = await res.data.Item;
        items[0]
          ? (fullInventory = fullInventory.concat(items))
          : fullInventory.push(items);

        if (i + 1 === queries) {
          return fullInventory;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("We have a problem here: ", error.response);
      }
    }, 2000 * i);
  };
}
```

Comment: try this 
localStorage.setItem('inv', JSON.stringify(inv))

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('inv') === undefined` is not true ... perhaps `localStorage.getItem('inv') === null` is (since `.getItem` returns `null` not `undefined` if the property doesn't exist) - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) ... you could test `localStorage.inv === undefined` though

Comment: I forgot it had to be a string :), but still isn't working :(. Maybe it's my getInventory script.

Comment: still `localStorage.getItem('inv') === undefined` is never true

Comment: If I set localStorage.getItem('inv') === null, getInventory() isn't triggered. And, there definitelty isn't anything in localStorage?

Comment: OK, must be some weird next.js thing then, because the specification states that `localStorage.getItem` returns `null` if the key doesn't exist, not `undefined`

Comment: oh, you're not returning anything from `getInventory`

Comment: Ok, you are right, I did start with null but an error led me to change it to undefined. Thanks for confirming that it should be null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222397/discussion-between-darryl-morley-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: try [this code](https://pastebin.com/26ReRDZu) for getInventory - I think I fixed most mistakes :p

Comment: Thanks for trying to tidy up my code, unfortuantly it fails with `res is not defined`, but also I think that when you return fullInventory it is an empty array?